# Getting a Heap Buffer Overflow not sure if allocating memory for a 2d array properly in C

Tags: arrays, c, malloc, overflow, heap-memory

I'm having an issue copying strings from an input string on the command line to strings in a 2d array. My program must separate strings made of letters from any non letter characters. For instance hello23ght.!good needs to be put into a 2d array as:

- hello
- ght
- good

I have already found the longest string and and the number of strings so that I can allocate memory for my 2D array as follows.

```
char **stringArr; //array to hold seperated strings

stringArr = (char **)malloc(numOfStrings * sizeof(char*)); //malloc rows of 2d array

if(stringArr == NULL) { //checks to see if memory was allocated correctly
    return 1;
}


int y; 
for (y = 0; y < numOfStrings; y++) { //malloc columns of array
    stringArr[y] = (char*) malloc((longestString + 1) * sizeof(char));

    if(stringArr[y] == NULL) { //checks to see if memory was allocted correctly
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Afterword I wrote this code to find individual letter strings within the input string and put each letter string into one "slot" of the 2d array:

```
while (argv[1][a] != '\0') { // Keep traversing the argument until the null char is reached
    if (isAlpha(argv[1][a]) == 1) { // if the first char in argv[1] is a letter, copy it into the first row and first column of stringArr
        stringArr[b][c] = argv[1][a];
        printf("%c" , stringArr[b][c]); //test
        a++; 
        c++;
        //printf("%d %d \n", a, c);
    } else if (a > 0 && isAlpha(argv[1][a]) != 1 && isAlpha(argv[1][a-1]) == 0) { //If the previous character is a letter and the current character isn't a letter increment a and b. (We have hit the end of the first unique string)
        a++;
        stringArr[b][c+1] = '\0'; //Setting the null byte for the unique string
        b++; //incrementing b to the next unique string
        printf("%d %d %d \n", a, b, c);
        c = 0; // resetting c for the next unique string 
    } else {// if neither of the first two  statments occur only increment var a since we have hit a repeating separating character.
        a++;
    }
}
```

However, when I run the code I get the following error:

```
==46957==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x60200000ef37 at pc 0x000103a76b8c bp 0x7fff5c18a910 sp 0x7fff5c18a908
WRITE of size 1 at 0x60200000ef37 thread T0

    SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow ??:0 main
    Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
      0x1c0400001d90: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
      0x1c0400001da0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
      0x1c0400001db0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
      0x1c0400001dc0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
      0x1c0400001dd0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa 07 fa
    =>0x1c0400001de0: fa fa 07 fa fa fa[07]fa fa fa 00 06 fa fa 00 00
      0x1c0400001df0: fa fa 00 04 fa fa 00 06 fa fa fd fd fa fa fd fd
      0x1c0400001e00: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
      0x1c0400001e10: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
      0x1c0400001e20: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
      0x1c0400001e30: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
    Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
      Addressable:           00
      Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
      Heap left redzone:       fa
      Heap right redzone:      fb
      Freed heap region:       fd
      Stack left redzone:      f1
      Stack mid redzone:       f2
      Stack right redzone:     f3
      Stack partial redzone:   f4
      Stack after return:      f5
      Stack use after scope:   f8
      Global redzone:          f9
      Global init order:       f6
      Poisoned by user:        f7
      Container overflow:      fc
      Array cookie:            ac
      Intra object redzone:    bb
      ASan internal:           fe
      Left alloca redzone:     ca
      Right alloca redzone:    cb
    ==46957==ABORTING

hlowrdjAbort trap: 6
```

I'm not sure exactly what is wrong but I'm assuming its either I'm not allocating enough memory for the 2d array, or my while statement does not accurately copy the unique letter strings from the input strings.

**edit**
I forgot to add this but a, b, and c are indeed initialized to 0.

**edit2**
Here is how numOfStrings and longestString were retrieved

```
int j;
int numOfStrings=0, longestString=0, x=0;
//numOfStrings indicates total separated strings, longestString is the longest seperated string, x is the current length of the string

for (j = 0; argv[1][j] != '\0'; j++) { // Traversing through the input string
    if (isAlpha(argv[1][j])) { //If the current char is a letter x is incremented by 1
        x++;
    } else if (!isAlpha(argv[1][j]) && isAlpha(argv[1][j-1])) { //If the current char is not a letter and the previous char is a letter then increment numberOfStrings by 1
        numOfStrings++;
        if (x > longestString) { //Since we hit a non letter char, if the x val is greater than the current longest string, replace longestString with x. 
            longestString = x;
        }
        x = 0;
    }

}
if(isAlpha(argv[1][j - 1])) { //Checks the last character if it is a letter and then accounts for the string associated with that letter.
    numOfStrings++;
    if(x > longestString) { // If the last string is a the largest string then this will store its length in longestString 
        longestString = x;
    }
}
```

**edit3**
My isAlpha function

```
int isAlpha (char a){ 

    if ((65 <= a && a <= 90) || (97 <= a && a <= 122) ) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
} //Determines if a char is a letter or not using ASCII values. Returns 1 if true otherwise returns 0.
```

Comment: Add -g to your compiler flags, ASan will tell you exactly what line writes to the invalid address. That should be a pretty bright arrow pointing at the cause.

Comment: I don't know if your `isAlpha` function is anything like the library function `isalpha`, but `isalpha` is not specified to return `1`, it returns `0` or a nonzero value.

Comment: Before scanning `argv[1]`, did you initialize the variables `a`, `b` & `c`, with 0?

Comment: This: stringArr[b][c] looks fishy. While you can access 2D array with pointer to pointer, it is can dangerous to do so the reverse. You allocated your malloc in a for loop, and you are assuming malloc returned adjacent memory locations. This can clearly fail in multithreaded applications.

Comment: @WeatherVane I didn't realize there was an isalpha function, I'm new to C. However I have tested my function and it does work as intended.

Comment: @Makketronix I'm not sure by what you mean when you say it can be dangerous to do so the reverse. Also how would I malloc space for the 2d array without a for loop?

Comment: @SA97 `islapha` is part of the standard C library. You may using a third-party library that includes `isAlpha` or your installed C library has added such a function. Anyway, `isalpha` is guaranteed to return 0 on error, a **nonzero** on success. That means on success, it may be 1, but it also may be 8277289 or -288728. The important part is the **nonzero** in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing how you calculate `numOfStrings`, and `longestString`, and
with knowing how you initialized the running indices `a`, `b`, `c`, it's
difficult to know where you get the error:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    char **stringArr;

    // emulating your allocation
    stringArr = calloc(5, sizeof(char*));
    stringArr[0] = calloc(1, 100);
    stringArr[1] = calloc(1, 100);
    stringArr[2] = calloc(1, 100);
    stringArr[3] = calloc(1, 100);
    stringArr[4] = calloc(1, 100);

    if(argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s arg\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    int i = 0; // index for scanning argv
    int j = 0; // index of current stringArg buffer
    int k = 0; // index of (end of) string in stringArg[j]

    // state 0: alpha mode
    // state 1: non-alpha mode
    int state = 0;

    char c;

    while((c = argv[1][i++]))
    {
        if(isalpha(c))
        {
            if(state)
            {
                // previous character was a non-alpha
                // change state and reset indices
                state = 0;
                k = 0;
                j++;
            }

            stringArr[j][k] = c;
            stringArr[j][++k] = 0;
            continue;
        }

        // not alpha, ignoring
        state = 1;

        // if line starts with non-alpha
        if(j == 0 && i == 1)
            j--;
    }


    for(i = 0; stringArr[i][0]; ++i)
        puts(stringArr[i]);

    free(stringArr[0]);
    free(stringArr[1]);
    free(stringArr[2]);
    free(stringArr[3]);
    free(stringArr[4]);
    free(stringArr);

    return 0;
}
```

I've decided to store the state of the scanning in a variable. This makes for
smaller `if` conditions, it easier to read. And my version also handles the case
when the line starts with a non-alpha character.

The output is:

```
$ valgrind ./a 'hello23ght.!good'
==20478== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==20478== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==20478== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==20478== Command: ./a hello23ght.!good
==20478== 
hello
ght
good
==20478== 
==20478== HEAP SUMMARY:
==20478==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20478==   total heap usage: 7 allocs, 7 frees, 1,564 bytes allocated
==20478== 
==20478== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==20478== 
==20478== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==20478== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

**edit**

I think my guess is right, the initialization of your running indices `a`, `b`
and `c` or the way you calculate `numOfStrings` and `longestString` may be the problem.
I think that way you calculate `numOfStrings` and `longestString` may be wrong.
But without the code, it's hard to tell.

I replaced mine `while` loop with yours in my program, I deleted the `printf`s
and prior to that I initialized the running indices `a`, `b`, `c` to 0. I
didn't change the emulation of the memory allocation, so I know there is
enough room for the the example.

This is the result with your code:

```
$ valgrind ./a-ops-version 'hello23ght.!good'
==20877== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==20877== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==20877== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==20877== Command: ./a hello23ght.!good
==20877== 
hello
ght
good
==20877== 
==20877== HEAP SUMMARY:
==20877==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20877==   total heap usage: 7 allocs, 7 frees, 1,564 bytes allocated
==20877== 
==20877== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==20877== 
==20877== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==20877== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

**edit 2**

I've found the error in your code:

```
stringArr[b][c+1] = '\0';
```

This causes an error when `b` indexes the longest string. When this line is
executed, it means that the current character is not an alpha-character, so in
the previous loop you already incremented `c` by one. That's why when you read
the non-alpha, `c` is already the index of the `'\0'`-terminating byte, so for
the longest string you are writing beyond the bounds.

To illustrate this

`'?'` is an uninitialized character

```
input: hello23ght.!good

Up until b == 0, a == 4, c == 4

hello23ght.!good
    ^
    |
    a

                                 c
                                 |
                                 v
                 0   1   2   3   4   5
               +---+---+---+---+---+---+
stringArr[b]:  | h | e | l | l | o | ? |
               +---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

This is the result of

```
if (isAlpha(argv[1][a]) == 1) {
    stringArr[b][c] = argv[1][a];
```

Then you do

```
a++; 
c++;
```

So `a` is updated to 5 and the next character is read:

```
input: hello23ght.!good

Up until b == 0, a == 5, c == 5

hello23ght.!good
     ^
     |
     a

                                     c
                                     |
                                     v
                 0   1   2   3   4   5
               +---+---+---+---+---+---+
stringArr[b]:  | h | e | l | l | o | ? |
               +---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Because `'2'` is non-alpha, the `else` block is executed

```
} else {
    a++;
}
```

incrementing `a` once again, now it's 6.

The loop continus and the `else if` is evaluated to true, because the last
character is also non-alpha:

```
stringArr[b][c+1] = '\0';
```

is executed, but you are writting beyond the limit, because
`numOfStrings` is 5:

```
input: hello23ght.!good

Up until b == 0, a == 6, c == 5

hello23ght.!good
      ^
      |
      a

                                     c    c+1
                                     |     |
                                     v     v
                 0   1   2   3   4   5     6   
               +---+---+---+---+---+---+ 
stringArr[b]:  | h | e | l | l | o | ? |   beyond the bounds
               +---+---+---+---+---+---+ 

yields:
==22229== Invalid write of size 1
==22229==    at 0x108C0E: main (a.c:93)
==22229==  Address 0x51e64e6 is 0 bytes after a block of size 6 alloc'd
==22229==    at 0x4C2CF05: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:711)
==22229==    by 0x108A4B: main (a.c:62)
==22229==
```

To fix it, you have to remove the `+1`:

```
stringArr[b][c] = '\0';
```

Note that your algorithm will work **if and only if** the non-alphas come in
pairs, would you have this input `hello234ght.!good`, then you'll program will
crash because of the first `else if`, you would increment `b` and eventually you
are out of bounds of the double pointer.

Take a look at mine, with mine version you can have as many non-alphas as you
like.

I encourage you to learn and use a debugger. These kind of bugs are easy to
spot when stepping through a loop, because with a debugger you can see the values
of all your indices at every step.

One last smaller criticism:

In your `isAlpha` you have:

```
if ((65 <= a && a <= 90) || (97 <= a && a <= 122) )
```

This is not wrong, but I consider doing this a bad practice, the numbers look like
magic numbers, like where did you came up with this numbers? I know that these
are the ASCII codes for a-z and A-Z.

This is a far better practice

```
if (('A' <= a && a <= 'Z') || ('a' <= a && a <= 'z') )
```

1. It increases the readability because you don't have to look up in the ASCII table,
2. It makes your intention very clear, specially for someone who is reviewing
   your code.

Comment: I forgot to include the a, b, and c in my code on here but in my actual code they are all initialized to 0. Also for my variable numOfStrings and longestString, I believe the way I got them is correct as I have tested them out. For instance the input string hello23ght.!good resulted in numOfStrings being set to 3 and longestString being set to 5.

Comment: @SA97 can you edit your post the actual code that does the real calculation? Your `while` loop looks ok, I didn't find anything specific that was wrong. Look at this https://pastebin.com/fCaXDsbK this is the code I used to test your code. As you see, your loop is there (minus the `printf`s) and valgrind showed no errors. The error must be somewhere else.

Comment: @SA97 because  `isAlpha` is not in the standard C library, I had to write one. It could be that your `isAlpha` doesn't necessarily return 1 on success, that may cause problems in your loop.

Comment: I didn't realize that isalpha was in the standard library, so I created my own function. I'll post that as well in the question

Comment: @SA97 I've made an update of my answer, I've found your bug and I explain why it is a bug.